# What is the encoding format from request in android app

Tags: android, python-requests, decode

Im trying to get request data from android app via "Fiddler everywhere" and I can't to decode this.
Body example:

`EBgxTnfcvh3/nsTwXwYuscKQfjXYPCo2DTR5XrP6VWgF00x7Nh0mhpDC1c521HFmmjsxjrK0Pc5d5i6V0HSQq0Y=`

Headers:

```
Key: :method; Value: POST
Key: :scheme; Value: https
Key: content-length; Value: 88
Key: language; Value: EN
Key: user-agent; Value: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SM-G965N Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/107.0.5304.105 Mobile Safari/537.36-bohookedapp
Key: content-type; Value: application/json
Key: region; Value: ID
Key: accept; Value: application/json, text/plain, */*
Key: zone; Value: Africa/Nairobi
Key: platform; Value: 1
Key: version; Value: 101033
Key: x-requested-with; Value: com.bo.hooked
Key: sec-fetch-site; Value: cross-site
Key: sec-fetch-mode; Value: cors
Key: sec-fetch-dest; Value: empty
Key: accept-encoding; Value: gzip, deflate
Key: accept-language; Value: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

I tried to decode it in base64 but unfortunately get error.
I want to get json data.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a single decoder as a static property of Model, configure it once, and use it for all your Model decoding needs, both externally and internally.
Unsolicited thought: Honestly, I would only recommend doing that if you're seeing a measurable loss of CPU time or crazy heap growth from the allocation of additional JSONDecoders… they're not heavyweight objects, less than 128 bytes unless there's some trickery I don't understand (which is pretty common though tbh)

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
malloc_size(Unmanaged.passRetained(decoder).toOpaque())
```